# gradle conflicting transitive dependency not being included

Tags: gradle

I have a dependency, `my-project` that uses two dependencies that use different versions of `commons-lang3` but when I build my `war` artifact, `commons-lang3` is not included in the artifact. What could be wrong?

My `build.gradle` looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'war'

buildscript {
    repositories { 
        jcenter() 
    }
    dependencies { 
        classpath 'io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.3.0.RELEASE' 
    }
}

compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.7
    targetCompatibility = 1.7
}

configurations.all { 
    exclude group: 'commons-logging' 
}

repositories { 
    jcenter() 
    maven {
        credentials {
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
        }

        url "myrepo.com"
    }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports { 
        mavenBom 'io.spring.platform:platform-bom:1.1.2.RELEASE' 
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile "my.project:my-project:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"

    // Spring Framework
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-web'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc'
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-config'
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web'

    // Jackson
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind"

    // Logging
    compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api'
    runtime 'org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j'
    runtime 'org.logback-extensions:logback-ext-loggly:0.1.2'

    // Test
    testCompile 'junit:junit'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core'
    testCompile 'org.springframework:spring-test'

    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.web
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username = "${artifactory_user}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
            }

            if(project.version.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT')) {
                url "myrepo.com/libs-snapshot-local"
            } else {
                url "myrepo.com/libs-release-local"
            }
        }
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) { 
    gradleVersion = '2.4' 
}
```

**EDIT** Dependency diagram of `my.project:my-project`

`my-project` is a library project that my co-worker wrote that is dependent on two other library projects that contain `commons-lang3`. An example diagram would be

```
my.project:my-project:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
+---my.project:my-dependency-1:1.0.0
|   +---org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4
+---my.project:my-dependency-2:1.0.0
    +---org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2
```

Comment: I had to remove the Maven repository declarations, and the dependency on `my.project:my-project:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` to get it to build locally. When I ran `dependencies` the output did not contain `commons-lang3` (or any other Commons Lang JAR). Which dependency do you expect to have a dependency on Commons Lang?

Comment: @JohanStuyts look at my edit for the dependencies of `my-project`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the spring gradle dependency-management-plugin to 0.5.2.RELEASE and that fixed my problem.